# Autosize Visual Studio Designer based on the Page size

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

In my UWP app I have long pages with lots of content that user can scroll down. When modifying the XAML of a single page I'd like to see all the content of the page in Visual Studio Designer. I can change the Device option into device with higher resolution to view more content but this still leaves most of the content hidden. In the past when developing Windows 8.1 Store Apps there was an option to set device display size to auto. When developing UWP app this autosize option does not seem to exist anymore.

Is there a convenient way for setting the Desinger width and height to be the same as those of the page?

Comment: ctrl+mouse wheel to focus on part on which you are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a convenient way for setting the Desinger width and height to be the same as those of the page?

Xaml designer has not provided this set option that make designer width and height to be the same as page. But you could make your xaml designer display with suitable size that could make the page fill the visible area. We could select `Fit all` option where in the `Zoom`AutoSuggestBox.

[image]

Comment: I see. I added a new device to the list with 1280x10000 resolution that is enough to cover all the pages in my app. Far away from ideal but at least I can now view the changes I make to XAML.